# Register click on checkbox which is inside a button element

Tags: html

I have a **button** element which has a javascript function attached to it, and this element, contains an **input** checkbox. Is it possible somehow to check/uncheck this checkbox, without firing the buttons javascript function?

*I know that it is probably not a very good design, placing an input checkbox inside a button element, but I am trying to modify a plugin, and if possible, I would remain at my current design, because I would lose too much time on changing the whole design, time, which unfortunatly I can't afford:|*

EDIT: Sorry, placing my text in < and > tags, made them dissapear:|

EDIT2:

What I am trying to achieve is to use tablesaw to create a sortable data table. When clicking on one of the headers in a tablesaw table, if sortable is set, it sorts the table by the selected column. I would like to place a checkbox in the first header, to select all rows visible. This is how my td looks like:

```
 <th data-tablesaw-sortable-default-col="true" class="tablesaw-cell-persist 
 tablesaw-sortable-head tablesaw-sortable-ascending" scope="col" 
 data-tablesaw-priority="persist" data-tablesaw-sortable-col="true">
    <button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input id="test" name="test" type="checkbox">
        <label for="test">
          Information
        </label>
      </div>
    </button>
 </th>
```

The event to the button is attached by tablesaw with an onclick event, but I can modify that too, cause I have access to the source. So basicaly, what I would like that, if a click is made ON the input element, modify the checkbox state, if a click is made anywhere else on or in the button, fire the tablesaw event.

I don't think that the attached javascript event is the problem, check out the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/16d8kasp/

There is no event attached here, but the checkbox state can't be toggled anyway.

Comment: If you never want the javascript function to be called when the checkbox is clicked Could you comment out the javascript function call from the checkbox?

Comment: I want it to be called, when for example the text is clicked near the checkbox. But anyways, even if I comment out the javascript event, the checkbox state doesn't get updated.

Comment: could you post the code section that is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Jquery example. Might work for you -
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishoreworks/y7tqn2w2/1/)

```
    $("input#test").on("click",function(e){        
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: In your fiddle, the button clicked event fires, no matter where I click.

Comment: @adamBaranyai Only clicking the button will fire the event and you'll see an alert but if you click only checkbox than event won't fire. If its not what you expect. Than can you please expain your expectation a bit in deep as per the example in My Fiddle

Comment: Using Firefox 38.0.5, only the button can be clicked. I can't check the checkbox which is inside the button. But tested it in Chrome, and there it indeed works.